System.StackOverflowException was thrown
I created a C# Windows Forms Application using OOP, and my code looks right on paper. It is the first time I am getting this error and I don't know how to fix it. Please can you help?
Here is my code - Employee class:
public class Employee
{
    private int hoursWorked;
    private double ratePerHour;

    // Property structures (getter/setter methods)
    public int propHoursWorked
    {
        get { return hoursWorked; }
        set { hoursWorked = value; }
    }

    public double propRatePerHour
    {
        get { return ratePerHour; }
        set { ratePerHour = value; }
    }

    // Default constructor
    public Employee()
    {
        propHoursWorked = 0;
        propRatePerHour = 0.00;
    }

    // Parameterised constructor
    public Employee(int hw, double rph)
    {
        propHoursWorked = hw;
        propRatePerHour = rph;
    }

    // Methods
    public double calcBase()
    {
        return (propRatePerHour * propHoursWorked);
    }

    public double calcTax()
    {
        return (calcBase() * 0.15);
    }

    public double calcNet()
    {
        return (calcBase() - calcNet());
    }
}

Driver/button code:
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /// Declare variables
    int HoursWorked;
    double RatePerHour, BaseSalary=0, TaxDue=0, NetPay=0;

    // Input
    HoursWorked = int.Parse(txtHoursWorked.Text);
    RatePerHour = double.Parse(txtRatePerHour.Text);

    // Processing
    // Create an object using the class as a blueprint
    // Method 1 - Using the Default Constructor
    Employee objE = new Employee(HoursWorked, RatePerHour);

    BaseSalary = objE.calcBase();
    TaxDue = objE.calcTax();
    NetPay = objE.calcNet();

    // Output
    lblBaseSalary.Text = BaseSalary.ToString("C");
    lblTax.Text = TaxDue.ToString("C");
    lblNetPay.Text = NetPay.ToString("C");
}

I get this error - it just gets triggered at random places in the class:

Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.


There's an endless recursive call here:
public double calcNet()
{
    return (calcBase() - calcNet());
}

It's not clear what your intention was.

Silly me. You're a lifesaver. Cons of working so late at night :(

@EffectiveLongJumper if the answer has helped you, you should upvote/accept it

Aside from the infinite recursive call to calcNet where i think you meant return (calcBase() - calcTax()); there are a few other things that can improve the code and make it easier for you:
When your getters/setters are that simple you can use auto-properties (since C#3) as they are just a more concise way of expressing the same behaviour.
They also support you giving them initial values as you do in your parameter-less constructor.
public int HoursWorked { get; set; } = 0;
Purely from a responsibility-viewpoint it does not make sense for an employee-class to calculate the tax-rate. But those can also be made a bit simpler with expression-bodied methods:
public double calcBase() => (RatePerHour * HoursWorked);

Now to the button action:
with this when creating an Employee you dont need to write your own constructor at all and instead use the object-initializers for that:
var poorEmployee = new Employee{HoursWorked: worktTime, hourRate: RatePerHour};
combining that gives us:
public class Employee
{
  public double HoursWorked {get; set;}
  public double RatePerHour {get; set;}
  private readonly double taxRate {get; set;} = 0.15;

  public double BaseSalary() => (propRatePerHour * propHoursWorked);
  public double TaxesDue() => (BaseSalary() * taxRate);

  public double NetIncome() => ( BaseSalary() - TaxesDue());
}

private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Input
  var workTime = double.Parse(txtHoursWorked.Text);
  var hourRate = double.Parse(txtRatePerHour.Text);

  // Create and Employee
  var poorEmployee = new Employee{HoursWorked: worktTime, hourRate: RatePerHour};

  // Output
  lblBaseSalary.Text = poorEmployee.BaseSalary().ToString("C");
  lblTax.Text = poorEmployee.TaxesDue().ToString("C");
  lblNetPay.Text = poorEmployee.NetIncome().ToString("C");
}

It can making writing code a lot easier if you don't have to write (and specially read) so much boilerplate clutter.
